# How to search a MySQL database for a specific string

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to set up a search feature on my site that will only return exact matches to keyword entered by the user. So if the user searches "dog" I don't want an article titled "Doggy Style" to appear in the search results (just an example I don't really have an article by that name). This of course does exactly that:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_title LIKE '%$searchQuery%'
```

$searchQuery here is a PHP variable taken from the user's input form. So is there any way to return only exact matches?

Comment: How do you define "exact" matches, case-sensitive and space-separated (e.g. "the dog walked" but not "doggy biscuit" or "Dog Eat Dog World")?

Comment: why you are not using Full text Search ?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @ drorhan I will look into it, seems interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_title = '$searchQuery'
```

would return an exact match. Notice the change from 'like' to '=' and notice the % signs have been removed.

Also be sure never to use direct input from a user form as input to search your MySQL database as it is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

For exact matches you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_title = '$searchQuery'
```

In MySql nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_title = '$searchQuery'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do like this, it works perfect.

SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_title='$searchQuery'

execute(array('%'.$searchQuery.'%'))

Comment: What does this add 7 years later which other answers don't provide?